# Justify where a series converges

Tags: real-analysis

At my disposal I have the cauchy criterion, the root test, the ration test, and the comparison test.

The series is 1/[n+(-1)^n]^2, n from 2 to infinity

I am trying to use the comparison test and compare say that this is less than or equal to

1/(n-1)^2

But the other tests don't really give me any usable result.  I understand the concept of absolute convergence as well, but I don't think that really applies here, since n is from 2 to infinity.

Comment: The terms go to $0$ too slowly for Ratio Test or Root Test to give any information. Absolute convergence is basically irrelevant, our terms are positive. Convergence is unaffected by the first 17000 terms, so I don't understand your worry about starting at $2$.  The Comparison you did works fine.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so do I just say the one I compared it to satisfies the cauchy criterion?  Because the sequence 1/(n-1)^2 is convergent?

Comment: The standard tool for series like $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ and relatives is the integral test. One can use Cauchy Criterion  by using an integral estimate or noting that $\frac{1}{k^2}\le \frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$ and then one can use telescoping for the estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well all you need is one criterion to give you a result and this can be achieved using the comparison test as you already stated. We have
$$\frac{1}{[n + (-1)^n]^2} \leq \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$$
because $(-1)^n \geq -1$. This gives you
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{[n+(-1)^n]^2} \leq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}< \infty$$

A more 'in-depth' look at the series would show you that this is nearly an equality: Let $a_n = ([n+(-1)^n]^2)^{-1}$. Then 
$$a_{2k} = \frac{1}{[2k + (-1)^{2k}]^2} = \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$$
and
$$a_{2k+1} = \frac{1}{[2k+1 + (-1)^{2k+1}]^2} = \frac{1}{(2k)^2 }.$$ 
This means that the series is just the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 1/n^2$ where the terms for even and odd $n$'s are switched.
$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{[n+(-1)^n]^2} = \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} - 1 = \frac{\pi^2}{6} -1.$$